# Why the pre_get_posts hook can cause apache stopped working?

Tags: query, pre-get-posts

I'm having all my posts with a Custom Field named `'validity'` where I'm assigning dates until the post is valid. My taxonomy archives are showing all the posts. Now I want to filter there, and exclude the posts that are not valid.

I wrote:

```
function e_exclude_posts( $query ) {
   if( $query->is_tax('my_tax') ) {
       $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 530 ) );
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'e_exclude_posts' );
```

It's excluding my post #530.

Now I want to make the query a more dynamic, so I made another function:

```
function g_get_all_the_expired_posts(){
    $this_time = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ); //Time now
    $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'posts',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'meta_key'      => 'validity',
            'meta_value'    => $this_time,
            'meta_compare'  => '<='
        );
    $expired_posts_array = get_posts( $args );

    $expired_posts = array();
    foreach ( $expired_posts_array as $expired_post ) {
        $expired_posts[] .= $expired_post->ID;
    }

    return $expired_posts;
}
```

and made my previous function a little change, from:

```
$query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 530 ) );
```

to:

```
$expired = g_get_all_the_expired_posts();
$query->set( 'post__not_in', $expired );
```

But only the `$expired = g_get_all_the_expired_posts();` line became enough to make it an infinite loop, and shut the apache.

I then solved the problem by declaring a global variable:

```
$EXPIRED_POSTS = g_get_all_the_expired_posts(); //set it a global variable

function e_exclude_posts( $query ) {
   ...
   global $EXPIRED_POSTS;
   $query->set( 'post__not_in', $EXPIRED_POSTS );
   ...
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'e_exclude_posts' );
```

But I can't understand why the first approach causes such an infinite loop or something that made apache an overload or something so that it appears with an error?

> Apache HTTP Server has stopped working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this WPSE thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57019/22728) you are actually putting overload to the apache. That's why it's reacting like that. :)

So let's cut the overload, use [`is_main_query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) properly, and just add a simple conditional to your `pre_get_posts` hooked function:

```
function e_exclude_posts( $query ) {
   if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax('my_tax') ) {
       $expired = g_get_all_the_expired_posts(); //now this won't create a problem
       $query->set( 'post__not_in', $expired );
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'e_exclude_posts' );
```

#### WHY?

The Codex says:

> This function is most commonly used within hooks to distinguish WordPress' main query (for a page, post, or archive) from a custom/secondary query.

So by appending this conditional we are actually saying WordPress to stick only with the main query, and not to do things for all the queries - so we are cutting the overload and let the apache some relief. :)

#### EDIT

as Pieter Goosen suggested to use `!is_admin()` to do the query modification only on front-end, I edited my answer and added the conditional. Thanks Pieter.

#### EDIT #2

And adding a global variable is a bad idea, as even the content of that global variable is not needed, the global variable will simply load the content on every load - that surely is an overkill. So the best way doing this is to call the function within the function as shown in this answer. Thanks to [@userabuser](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22005937#22005937) and @PieterGoosen for their expert advices.

Comment: Two notes here, for any page outside the home page, **always** do a check for admin pages and front end pages, `pre_get_posts` alters the back end queries as well. Add `!is_admin()` check. Also, avoid creating globals, they are evil. Create an evil list and add creating globals and `query_posts` right on top of this list ;-)